# Severe lag when opening "Files", xdg-open: "timeout was reached"

Tags: nautilus, xdg-open

After a recent update "Files" either times out, or takes a significantly long time to open a file manager window.

When attempting to open window via 'xdg-open .', I encounter "gio: file:///home/userName: Timeout was reached"

How do I fix this issue?
Where do I look to fix this issue?